# como salvar objetos em django com validação de quantidade?

Tags: python, django, relacionamento

Ainda sou iniciante em `Django` e gostaria de saber como eu faria pra salvar uma certa quantidade de alunos em vagas.

**Exemplo:** `vagas = 5`, como faço pra permitir que só sejam salvos *5 alunos*?

```
class Turma(models.Model):  
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    vagas = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    horario = models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=HORARIO_CHOICES,null=False,blank=False,verbose_name='Turno')
    ano = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    semestre = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=SEMESTRE_CHOICES,null=False,blank=False)
    aluno = models.ManyToManyField(Aluno,verbose_name='Aluno')
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor,verbose_name='Professor')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.descricao)
```

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é criar um [validador customizado](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/) em `Aluno` e nesse validador fazer um `count` na tabela `Aluno` checando se já tem 5 alunos relacionados àquela turma.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar os próprios `validators` do Django. Como o [MaxValueValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator), que vai

> lançar um `ValidationError` [...] se o `value` for maior que o `max_value` (traduzido e encurtado da doc).

O seu field então ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
vagas = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(5)])
```